# hook_menu not working for me, neither helloworld example

Tags: drupal-7, cron, hook-menu

I waste all day fighting with drupal 7 hook_menu, days ago all was working when i create new modules, new menu entries, etc.

Im developing a cron, depends of 1 parameter, its generate a file to output, or read other file (input).

I trying to define a simple url to test the cron, and when i put ...lec_profile_cron in the brosers, it works, but if try ....companies_cron/1 or just companies_cron o other name y put at $items['route'], its doesnt works.

I tried to clean cache, memcached, use drush rr, all and dont understand what is happen.

I tried a lot of combinations and examples like the helloword_hello menu option in a new module i create called helloworld, and its returns 404 not found.

```
// CRON TEST
$items['companies_cron/%out'] = array(
    'title' => t('Test cron'),
    'page callback' => 'lec_profile_cron',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access arguments' => array('administer lec profile configuration')
);

function lec_profile_cron($out)
{
    // CRON OUT
    if ($out == 1) {
        //do stuff
    } else {
        //CRON IN
    }
}
```

Maybe was a stupid thing, but i cant find...

Ty in advice.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation I think this will work better. You dont need th %out for args in your $items and I also think you missing the trailing comma on 'access arguments' which I've added and also returning something.

```
$items['companies_cron'] = array(
'title' => t('Test cron'),
'page callback' => 'lec_profile_cron',
'page arguments' => array(1),
'access arguments' => array('administer lec profile configuration'),
return $items;

);

function lec_profile_cron($out = 0){
// If companies_cron/ is called, $out takes default value of 0
// If companies_cron/1 is called, $out value will be 1
// To pass multiple args, like companies_cron/1/2, you would require further params with defaults like $out = 0, $in = 0 ...

// CRON OUT
if ($out == 1) {
    //do stuff
} else {
    //CRON IN
}
};
```

Comment: I have the return $items im my code, i copy just that items['companies_cron'] definition, instead the comma have no sense, in fact is better dont write commas if there isnt more array positions. And you forgive a close ) before the return. In fact your answer is wrong, but thanks for your time.

Comment: Actually, I beg to differ. Also, I was trying to help. Not pass a test as by your own admission, your code was not syntactically correct anyway. Trailing commas are considered to best practice in arrays in  Drupal by many. Drupal has lots of arrays, in many of these arrays, the order is not so significant as the key names, so someone can quickly sort a long array by its keys and not have to worry if the last line has a comma or not. Some helpful info https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7